# How to customize a Spinner so that it opens to the Top ?

Tags: java, android, spinner

The normal Spinner in Android opens like a dropdown menu.
So my question is, if it is possible to open it in the the other direction, upwards?

Comment: You can have a look at this : http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Allready solved it by putting the Spinner on the Bottom of the Layout, so it opend to the top. Didn't know that before.